# Getting city and country from GoogleGeocoder response

Tags: flutter, google-geocoder

I need to make use of the google_geocoding package.

My code for it is:

```
Future<GeocodingResponse> getDatosGeocoding () async {
    var resultado= (await googleGeocoding.geocoding.getReverse(LatLon(40.714224,-73.961452))) ;
    
    return resultado;

  }
```

I have been searching the package readme and I was unable to find out how to get the city and country from the GeocodingResponse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interface unfortunately is not that granular to directly get city and country as separate values.

But maybe this code snippet will help you:

```
final response = await googleGeocoding.geocoding.getReverse(LatLon(lat, lng));

if (response != null && response.results != null) {
  final geocodingResponse = response.results;
  if (geocodingResponse != null) {
    if (geocodingResponse.isNotEmpty) {
      final address = geocodingResponse[0].formattedAddress;
      if (address != null) {
        // address is available
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Instead of `formattedAddress` you could maybe also try to see what values `addressComponents` contains. Unfortunately the [documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/google_maps_webservice/latest/google_maps_webservice.geocoding/GeocodingResult-class.html) is not very specific.

Comment: let my try, thank you

Comment: I am getting an empty result:   if (resultado != null && resultado.results != null) {
      print("RESUltado1:");
      final geocodingResponse = resultado.results;
      if (geocodingResponse != null) {
        print("RESUltado2:");
        if (geocodingResponse.isNotEmpty) {
          print("RESUltado3:");
          final address = geocodingResponse[0].formattedAddress;
          if (address != null) {
            // address is available
            print("RESUltado4:"+address);
          }
        }
      }
    }

Comment: i am getting printed our resultado1 and resultado2, but not the address

Comment: This could happen if your API key is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

I use this and it works perfectly for me
geocoding: ^ 2.0.0

Comment: Thank you, but I need to use google_geocoding as said in  my question

Comment: With that you can also do whatever you want, I use it for that, that's why I recommended it to you

Comment: I know, but for some reason, the current project that I need to update doesn't accept that package, I am getting an error during the execution if geocoding package is installed